# converting date format using javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a simple textfield with the type defied to be as date which attached with a jquery `datepicker()`. Now i have set the `dateFormat()` to be `dd-mm-yy`. All this works fine. But as i know MySql requires date in `yyyy-mm-dd`. So i was just wondering if i can convert that date format either using php or javascript to enter into the database.

E.g `var date = $('#order_date').val();` gives value 26-2-2012. I need to convert this into 2012-02-26.

**Note:** There is also a `0` being added to the month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use PHP:

```
$date = $_POST['date']; // e.g. 06-08-2011
$mysql_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
```

or

```
$date = explode('-', $_POST['date']);
$mysql_date = $date[2].'-'.$date[1].'-'.$date[1];
```

use $mysql_date to insert into the database.

Answer (score 2):

You can do in javascript by parsing the input and loading it into a Date() object, and then using the getMonth, getDate, and getFullYear functions, as follows:

```
        //Assume input is dd-mm-yyyy
        var dateParts = $('#order_date').val().split("-");
        var date = new Date(dateParts[2], (dateParts[1] - 1), dateParts[0]);

        //format using getMonth(), getDate() and getFullYear() methods)
        var formattedMonth = date.getMonth() + 1 < 10 ? '0' + (date.getMonth() + 1) : (date.getMonth() + 1);
        var formattedDate = date.getDate() < 10 ? '0' + date.getDate() : date.getDate();
        var output = date.getFullYear() + '-' + formattedMonth + '-' + formattedDate;
```

You can see more at this excellent [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

Answer (score -1):

did u try `date.format("yyyy-mm-dd");` ?
u can also use `"isoDate"` in place of `"yyyy-mm-dd"`

and if u are using mysql u can use DATE_FORMAT(date,'%Y-%m-%d')

Comment: Yeah, because `date` is a string, not a `Date` object.

Comment: i figured out that u must create a format function. in that case Joe's answer will work.